# Change mapping rules for view model AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, automapping

I have a model

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            private set{_name = value;}
        }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Depth { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        ...
        public string GeneralInfo {get{//some get logic}...}
}
```

and a View model:

```
public sealed class ProductDetailsModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Depth { get; set; }
        ...
        public string GeneralInfo {get;set;}
}
```

and controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  ...

public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var product = _productRepository.GetProduct(id);
            var productViewModel = Mapper.Map<ProductDetailsModel>(product);
            return View(productViewModel);
        }
  ...
}
```

everything works great, BUT... I have some get logic for product model general info property, which gets this general info from database, and sometimes, when product doesn't have general info, this property returns null. What I need is to generate alternative general info from available properties such as With, Height, etc. Something like:

```
private string GenerateGeneralInfoFromProductProperties()
        {
            var generalInfoStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            generalInfoStringBuilder.Append(@"<b>Width: </b>").Append(Width).Append("</br>");
            generalInfoStringBuilder.Append(@"<b>Weight: </b>").Append(Weight).Append("</br>");
            ...
            return generalInfoStringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

If I add this logic to product model ...

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    public string GeneralInfo
        {
            get
            {
                var gInfo = getGeneralInfoFromBD();
                if (gInfo==null) 
                     gInfo = GenerateGeneralInfoFromProductProperties();
                return gInfo;
            }
            set { SetPropertyValue(ProductPropertyType.GeneralInfo, value); }
        }
}
```

Everything works fine, BUT it would be wrong and illogical, because I have a view model for representation of product details, so I want to add this logic to view model, but my view model instance is created by mapper, Product view model has no constructors to pass product instance to get it's general info, because, as I said, it has no need in constructor. How can I add this "general info if null" replace logic to mapper, or view model?

Answer (score 0):

Try AfterMap

```
Automapper.CreateMap<Product,ProductDetailsModel>()
    .AfterMap((p,pm) => {  
       // now you have access to both objects, so you can do whatever you please
     });
```